# Trying to parse this json file and store it in php

Tags: php, json, swifty-json

I am trying to parse this json file but I cannot store it as an array in php. I have been having a problem with accessing the objects of the json file as i get an "Illegal string offset 'name' error.

My code is as follows:

This is my json:

```
"{\"Data\":[{\"id\":21,\"name\":\"Parle G\",\"item_code\":\"PG4\"},{\"id\":22,\"name\":\"Dark Fentasy\",\"item_code\":\"DF\"}]}"
```

Here is where I am trying to read the file but I can't access the objects

```
<?php

// Read JSON file
$json = file_get_contents('results.json');

//Decode JSON
$json_data = json_decode($json);

 //print_r($json_data);

echo $json_data[0]['name'];

?>
```

Could anybody help me through this please?

Comment: try `var_dump($json_data)` to see the structure of the object

Comment: `C:\wamp64\www\json\testt.php:10:string '{"Data":[{"id":21,"name":"Parle G","item_code":"PG4"},{"id":22,"name":"Dark Fentasy","item_code":"DF"}]}" ` Thats what i  get @KarstenKoop

Comment: seems you have twice encoded json. for now, try decoding it twice, too. and for the future: check where the data is encoded and fix it.

Comment: Yes this worked perfectly and stored it as an array for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to use this as an Array you will have to cast it into it like:

```
$json_data = (array) json_decode($json);
```

This will get all Fields from JSON into an PHP Array:

```
Array ( [Data] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 21 [name] => Parle G [item_code] => PG4 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 22 [name] => Dark Fentasy [item_code] => DF ) ) )
```

Alternativ you can casting the data into an Object, so you will have to access fields like `$json_data->Data[0]->name`

```
$json_data = (object) json_decode($json);
```

Read more in the `json_decode` Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Why are you doing the casting when the json_decode method converts it to an Object by default and json_decode also accepts a parameter to convert to an array as mentioned in the docs you reference?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
```

That will convert json to associative array

And then try:

```
echo $json_data['Data'][0]['name'];
```

Comment: I used json_decode twice and it stored it as an associative array like this. `stdClass Object ( [Data] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 21 [name] => Parle G [item_code] => PG4 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 22 [name] => Dark Fentasy [item_code] => DF ) ` However when i try to parse, It tells me `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\wamp64\www\json\testt.php on line 9` What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// Read JSON file
$json = file_get_contents('http://192.168.1.100:8080/demo_phonegap/webservices/result.json');

//Decode JSON
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);



    echo json_encode($json_data);



?>
```

Here you need to set full path of the JSON file to read JSON File.
and use $json_data = json_decode($json, true); to decode the JSON File.

Hope this will help you.